# Can't install policycoreutils-python on Centos 6.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos, centos6

It appears that `policycoreutils-python` requires higher versions of 
the packages : `libsemanage-python`, `auditlibs-python` and `python-IPy`, than the default versions of these packages I have installed on a Centos server (Rocks 6.1). I thought that updating the version of Python would help since the default Python version on the server is 2.6.6.

I installed Python 3.5 by following another answer:

`yum install https://centos6.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm`

and then installing `python35u` through yum. 
Since 3.5 is not default and only one of the python versions available, I am not sure how to make yum use this version while installing `policycoreutils-python`.

I am interested in installing `policycoreutils-python` because I want to update the version of GCC to >=4.7 through the [developer toolset package](http://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/devtoolset/) 
released by the Scientific Linux community.

My questions are therefore:
1. How do I get `policycoreutuils-python` installed?
2. Is it a good idea to update several different packages on the server, in the process? I am really new to Centos and I am not sure how to find packages
when yum reports that they are not available. What is the best practice - install from source?

Answer (score 1):

---

1) CentOS 6.5 is too old to be updated. I.e. please run # `yum update` every week. CentOS 6.5 was released 'Dec 2013' ! ( And no 'yum install [package] will work anymore ? ? ).

2) Generally always use yum for any package install. And : policycoreutils-python is included in the *Base.repo http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.8/os/x86_64/Packages/ . And : a package search should always be used : # `yum search policycoreutils-python` ... i.e. # yum search [name] , or [part of name] .

3) If your old CentOS 6.5 works anyway, the right policycoreutils-python etc. will be installed automatically when installing gcc-4.7 : # `yum install devtoolset-1.1-gcc-c++` ... : You don't need to install the complete devtoolset-1.1 .

**Important** : The slc6-devtoolset.repo must be setup beforehand : # `wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/slc6-devtoolset.repo http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/devtoolset/slc6-devtoolset.repo`

Ref. http://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/devtoolset/

---